# Usar propiedad value dentro de la llamada a una función

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Estoy tratando de utilizar el método `getElementById.Value()`  para pasarlo como un parámetro a un método en un controlador de evento. El código que llevo probado es el siguiente:

```
metodo(document.getElementById('txtTexto').value);
```

El problema es que no me aparece la propiedad `value`. Necesito obligatoriamente hacerlo de esta manera. ¿Alguna idea?

Éste es el código que tengo:

```
<input type="text" id="txtTexto" name="txtTexto" [(ngModel)]="texto">
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-inverse">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre del Archivo</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let archivo of archivos; let i = index" onclick="cargarArchivo(document.getElementById('txtTexto'))">
        <td>{{archivo.NombreImagen}}</td>
        <td><button>Editar</button></td>
        <td><button>Eliminar</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Y su DOM tiene realmente un elemento con `id="txtTexto"`?  ¿Qué tipo de elemento es, un `input`, un `div` un ....?  Sería conveniente [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/164403/edit) para   mostrar el contenido HTML sobre el que intenta implementar ese código y el contexto en Javascript en el que funciona `metodo`, qué evento lo desencadena, etc.

Comment: metodo(document.getElementById('txtTexto').value); qué sale si pones esto en la consola del navegador?

Comment: Pienso que con esto se puede guiar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26793040/8933039

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto se puede hacer de distintas formas.

- La más flexible sería obtener el elemento por su `id` (Forma A) y a continuación el valor del mismo. La ventaja de este método es que obteniendo el elemento por su `id`, podremos tener acceso a otras propiedades del mismo si fuera necesario y además el código queda independiente del elemento en sí en el DOM.
- O puedes pasar el valor del elemento como parámetro a la función (Forma B). Esta función hace el código más dependiente, y si quieres otros datos contenidos en el elemento, tendrás que recurrir de todos modos a `document.getElementById`.

Aquí tienes una prueba de ambas formas, yo optaría por la A.

```js
function cargarArchivo() {
  var elInput = document.getElementById('txtTexto');
  console.log(elInput.value);
}

function cargarArchivoDirecto(valor) {
  console.log(valor);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtTexto" name="txtTexto" placeholder="Escribe nombre del archivo" value="Test.txt" />
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-inverse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre del Archivo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Archivo</td>
      <td><button onclick="cargarArchivo()">Cargar (Forma A)</button></td>
      <td><button onclick="cargarArchivoDirecto(document.getElementById('txtTexto').value)">Cargar  (Forma B)</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**P.D.:**

Incluso hay una práctica todavía mejor que es no poner ninguna función dentro de los elementos HTML, creándolas mediante *listeners* en el mismo Javascript. De este modo, si hay que cambiar algo cambias solamente la función de JS y no tienes que modificar el HTML (esto es particularmente útil en proyectos grandes).

Suponte que tienes que recorrer decenas, cientos o miles de archivos para cambiar la función o los parámetros de elementos creados así: `<button onclick="cargarArchivoDirecto(document.getElementById('txtTexto').value)">Cargar  (Forma B)</button>` o creados así: `<button onclick="cargarArchivoDirecto()">Cargar  (Forma A)</button>`.

El código es más independiente si tú creas el botón así: `<button id="btnCargar">Cargar</button>` y luego, desde Javascript asignas un *listener*  a ese botón mediante su id.

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario utilizar `document.getElementById()` simplemente pasa el id de tu input y llamas a la variable `value` de ese objeto. Ejemplo

```js
function MiFuncion(valor){
  console.log("El valor pasado es "+valor);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="MiInput"></input>
<input type="button" value="Pasar valor" onClick="MiFuncion(MiInput.value)"></input>
```

Comment: Aunque la mayoría de los navegadores lo soportan, acceder a un elemento usando su id en lugar de seleccionándolo con getElementById (u otro método de selección) no es un comportamiento estándar y no es una buena práctica (el resultado puede no ser el esperado).